# When verbatim is loaded, \verb behaves as \verb*

Tags: verbatim

With recent versions of LaTeX, when the package `verbatim` is loaded, the standard command `\verb` always behaves as `\verb*`. Is it a feature or a bug?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}

\verb|Some text.|

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: It is a (known) bug. https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1160

Comment: why on earth did someone downvote?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this is not lonely case. As I observed a downvoter (incognito, (without any reason) is on raid (again). Sadly and shameful ...